# Concatenate char embeddings and word embeddings

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, word-embedding

I want to use char sequences and word sequences as inputs. Each of them will be embedded its related vocabulary and then resulted embeddings will be concatenated. I write following code to concatenate two embeddings:

```
char_model = Sequential()
char_model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, char_emnedding_dim,input_length=char_size,embeddings_initializer='random_uniform',trainable=False, input_shape=(char_size, )))

word_model = Sequential()
word_model.add(Embedding(word_vocab_size,word_embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_length, trainable=False,input_shape=(max_length, )))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Concatenate([char_model, word_model]))
model.add(Dropout(drop_prob))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=250, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides = 1))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(hidden_dims)) # fully connected layer
model.add(Dropout(drop_prob)) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
print(model.summary())
```

When I execute the code, I have the following error:

```
ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling build() or calling fit() with some data. Or specify input_shape or batch_input_shape in the first layer for automatic build.
```

I defined `input_shape` for each embedding, but I still have same error. How can I concatenate two sequential model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
model.add(Concatenate([char_model, word_model]))
```

Let alone you are calling `Concatenate` layer wrongly, you can't have a concatenation layer in a Sequential model since it would no longer be a Sequential model by definition. Instead, use [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to define such a model.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can concatenate after converting the model from sequential to functional.

Comment: Do you have the solution that you implemented?  It would be a big benefit